# jQuery UI Position of parent functions jQuery-object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, positioning, this

I have a popup I want to show at the location of the clicked link - and I wish to reuse the same popupwindow. So if another link is pressed when the popup is already displayed, I want it to fadeout before changing positions and performing a new slideDown. This means using a subfunction - but the position function doesn't seem to accept the referred Jquery object. No Errors, just not displaying the div. Any suggestions?? Thanks!

Code:

```
       $('.txtTd').click(function() {
            var selector=$(this);

            if ( $("#popupHelpTxt").is(':visible') ) {
                $("#popupHelpTxt").fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $("#popupHelpTxt").slideDown(200).position({
                        my:        "left top",
                        at:        "left bottom",
                        of:        selector, 
                        offset:     "0, 0",
                        collision: "fit"
                     });
                 });
            } else {
                $("#popupHelpTxt").slideDown(200).position({
                    my:        "left top",
                    at:        "left bottom",
                    of:        this,
                    offset:     "0, 0",
                    collision: "fit"
                });
            }
      });
```

It does work (with a malpositioned popup) if i replace 'selector' with something else in the position argument.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting this `.position()` method that takes an object. I don't see that in [standard jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: I'm also not familiar with'position', is it JS only? Try `var selector = $(this)[0];`

Comment: Sorry if unclear! It's a jQuery UI function! Thanks for the proposed solutions but they are not working.

Comment: @Kyle . It's a jQuery UI function! To fill you in a little bit: It will position the div aligned to '#popupHelpTxt' (itself, that is) if I move the expression `var selector=$(this);` into  `$("#popupHelpTxt").fadeOut(200, function() {`...

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery UI position documentation:

> Utility script for positioning any widget relative to the window,
>   document, a particular element, or the cursor/mouse.
>
> **Note: jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.**
>
> Does not need ui.core.js or effects.core.js.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

My suggestion would be to stick with fades, and write the fade functions manually with `animate`, and only adjust the `opacity` factor, not `display`

Comment: Thanks @kyle! I see what you mean but I doubt this is the problem since the code after else, _that is_ the code that displays and positions the div if it is indeed NOT visible - works just fine! I fiddled around a little and noticed that the div is indeed displayed, just further down and to the right, further away with each click - so far you have to scroll the window to see it.

Comment: Actually, no. The first function of `slideDown` is to set `display:block`, which makes it visible, so the code can execute. Your first function is in callback of `fadeOut`, so it doesn't execute until AFTER fadeOut sets `display:none`, which is the last step in fadeOut.

Comment: Tot test this, move the `slideDown` after the position statement. It shouldn't move it.

Comment: It still did move it when I moved slideDown after the position statement, this, however did the trick: `$("#popupHelpTxt").css('display','inline-block').position({
                my:        "left top",
                at:        "left bottom",
                of:        selector, 
                offset:     "0, 0",
                collision: "fit"
                }).css('display','none').slideDown(200);` It ain't pretty, but functionality is there. Suggestions? Thanks for your ideas so far!